# Cloning repository via visual studio shows error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2017, git-clone, git-credential-manager

I have a repository on git hub, and I'm trying to clone this repository to a different computer.
I'm going to the repository -> open in visual studio -> after the computer filled the repository address and the folder to save it, I'm pressing clone, but the following error happens:

> Git failed with a fatal error.
>
> fatal: AggregateException encountered.
>     One or more errors occurred.
>
> error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
>
> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled`

I have tried the following  :

change repository address to `git@github.com/User_Name/project_name.git`

also tried `https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/project.git`

what else should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloning repository from MSA backed Azure DevOps using Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 and AAD account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767132/cloning-repository-from-msa-backed-azure-devops-using-visual-studio-2017-or-2019)

Answer (score 0):

Your Visual studio 2017 installation has an older version of the Git credential manager for Windows. Upgrade to the latest version and configure this specific installation in your global git config to ensure Visual Studio is aware of the latest GCM that's available to it.

See also (different issue, same problem):

- [Cloning repository from MSA backed Azure DevOps using Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 and AAD account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767132/cloning-repository-from-msa-backed-azure-devops-using-visual-studio-2017-or-2019/54783656#54783656)