# Why do I have to sign in so many times?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I have a repository in Azure DevOps, and have the code in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, version 15.9.9. Every time I start VS and want to commit code or get the latest, the solution shows as not connected to any source control. I have to choose "Add to source control" from the VS status bar and choose Git, then it asks me to choose an account to use. It never remembers the fact that the solution is under source control from one time to the next.

On top of that, it will often pop up the window asking me to choose an account even when I've been working in the same instance of VS for some hours.

Every time this happens, I get an email telling me that an Azure DevOps personal access token added.

Why doesn't it remember the settings? I've been using SVN for years and never ever had anything like this.

**UPDATE** I just noticed that when this happens, I get the following in the Output panel...

> Opening repositories:
>
> C:\Users\Me\My web site
>
> Git failed with a fatal error.
>
> could not read Password for 'https://myusername@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled

Don't know if that's relevant, but though it worth adding in case

Comment: Which VS 2017 version do you use?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk VS2017. I think it's the Enterprise version

Comment: Which release? (Help => About => Version)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Please see the updated question. Thanks

Comment: 4.7 is the .Net framework version, not the version of VS.  VS 2017 has version numbers starting with `15`.

Comment: @Amy Duh, some sleep would help! I'll update the question with the right number. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk This is getting worse. Today it's asked me to choose the account pretty much every time I've committed, generating a personal token email every time. Any ideas?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I have no idea :/ try to change the VS version.

Comment: Likely related to an issue with the Git Credential Manager for Windows. Possible duplicate of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54767132/736079

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks for the suggestion, but I already have version 1.18.4 of the Git Credential Manager installed, so that's not it

Comment: Well 1.19 is out now... Maybe using that solves your issues https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, please try below ways:

1. Click your name and choose "Account settings", from my profile in the upper-right, then logged out.
2. Logged back in, then on the popup dialog,  click "**Check for an updated license**".

VS should be refreshing user license when click "Check for an updated license'.

Take a look at *Nicholas Westbrook*'s reply in this similar case [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/38667/vs-is-repeatedly-asking-me-to-login.html).

Another place to check is the default source control plug-in：

Open the project and go to Tools >> Options >> "Source Control" tab and select "Git" as your source control.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't help. I gave it a day or so to see, but it still keeps prompting me. I didn't see "Check for an updated license" anywhere though, so I don't know if that's significant. Any other ideas? Thx again.