# Azure Devops git credentials not authenticating when try doing git pull

Tags: azure-devops

I've set up a git repo in Azure Dev Ops and I'm trying to do a git pull to my computer via https. I set up a credential alias in Dev Ops (this seemed to be the only authentication method that worked for pulling originally).

When I pull to my computer I'm being prompted for the alias password (which is definitely correct, as is working on other computers). When I enter the password I'm getting the following error message:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for [git url]
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

The email address linked to the Dev Ops account has been added to the team members in Dev Ops (this was causing issues with git pulling on another computer, however this resolved that instance of the error)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783656/736079

Comment: You shouldn't need to use alternate credentials when Git Credential Manager is installed. It will prompt you for your real (not alternate) credentials and will generate a scoped Personal Access Token for you in the background.

Comment: Please add: git client you're using, what OS, git.exe version, git-credential-manager.exe version, what typo of account you use to access Azure DevOps (Work or School account vs Personal account).