# Git failure - cannot read user name for XXX.visualstudio.com

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

Tried sync in VS 2017 Team Explorer.

```
Sync failed.  Error was:
Git failed with a fatal error.
NullReferenceException encountered.
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
cannot spawn /c/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2017/community/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://******.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I am able to access the remote repo ok via browser.  Searching for "username" yields no results.  Not sure where to do or what to do.  Last successful synch was a month ago.

Cannot tell whether the problem is at remote, or in Team Explorer or in underlying git app.

How can I go back to successfully sytncing my local commits with the remote?

Comment: Can you try these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767132/cloning-repository-from-msa-backed-azure-devops-using-visual-studio-2017-or-2019?noredirect=1&lq=1 Visual studio 2017 ships with an old version of the Git Credential Manager for Windows, upgrading it may help.

Comment: See also: https://jessehouwing.net/configure-visual-studio-to-use-a-different-git-credential-manager-for-windows/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloning repository from MSA backed Azure DevOps using Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 and AAD account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767132/cloning-repository-from-msa-backed-azure-devops-using-visual-studio-2017-or-2019)

Comment: Upgrading to Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition should also upgrade the GCMfW.

Comment: The error message you pasted in the question says *"cannot spawn /c/.../git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory"*. A component or a plugin is missing or it is installed incorrectly/partially.