# Git fatal: could not read Username for 'https://dev.azure.com': terminal

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, azure-repos

I am trying to connect my project to my devops account, but i keep getting this error

[image]

I have created a repo on devops, and just want to push my code. I see that it cant "not read Username" and "canot spawn askpass".

I have been googling but no luck.

Comment: Is it really true that you "just want to push my code"? It appears from the screen shot that you are trying to _clone_.

Comment: yea, well, that might be because i am misunderstanding the way this should be done.

what i what int he end, is me code being in devops, so i can have some version control.

I have tried to push instead, then i get this error

Comment: Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
fatal: NullReferenceException encountered.
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
fatal: NullReferenceException encountered.
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
Pushing to https://username@dev.azure.com/xxx/yy/_git/yy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloning repository from MSA backed Azure DevOps using Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 and AAD account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767132/cloning-repository-from-msa-backed-azure-devops-using-visual-studio-2017-or-2019)

Comment: See: https://jessehouwing.net/configure-visual-studio-to-use-a-different-git-credential-manager-for-windows/